# Is it possible to delete an item from a List without referencing its INDEX?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of `Cards`, `Card` is a class that has some methods like `getRank()`.

I want to delete `Cards` from the `List` by referring to its `rank` not by the `id`. I know that there is a method `myList.remove(index)` but I want to delete the `Cards` by referring to the card rank. how can I do this?

Comment: You're confusing me. You said "want to delete Cards from the List by referring to its rank" and then you said "I want to delete the Cards by referring to the card id". Which one is it?

Comment: you would have to find the position of the item based on its id and then remove it. But you will need the position to remove it

Comment: Iterate over your List and check if the Rank is equal to the Rank of the item you want to delete, if so ? delete the item. But you have to use an iterator, otherwise it will end up in ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @Akagami so sorry, i corrected the typo

Comment: `List#remove` accepts either the index of the object to remove or the object itself. There's no such terminology like _id_.

Comment: @kai thank you. would you mind providing me an exaple?

Comment: @kai right, i corrected this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will remove all `Card` objects having a given `rank` from `list`:

```
list.removeIf(card -> card.getRank() == rank);
```

This method exists since Java 8. Prior to Java 8 you will have to use an `Iterator` instead:

```
Iterator<Card> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next().getRank() == rank) iter.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how Card is written, but try something like

```
 myList.remove( new Card( Card.Rank.JACK, Card.Suit.HEART ) );
```

to remove a card based on rank *and* suit.

If you want to remove all cards of a certain rank, you'll have to iterate the array list and test individually:

```
for( int i = myList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
    if( myList.get(i).getRank == Card.Rank.KING ){
        myList.remove( i );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList implementation in java has *no id reference*. You have two ways to delete an object:
1. Delete by *index*.
2. Delete by passing through object - which will be compared to each object in array with *equals()* method.